# Import multiple text files in R and assign them names from a predetermined list

Tags: r, text, import

I just started using R and I am having trouble performing the following task: I have approximately 130 language samples in separate plain text files sitting in my working directory. What I would like to do is import them using scan and retain their file names. 
Specifically, what I would like to do is using something like:

```
Patient01.txt <-scan("./Patient01.txt", what = "character")
Patient02.txt <-scan("./Patient02.txt", what = "character")
...
Patient130.txt <-scan("./Patient130.txt", what = "character")
```

Is there a way to use a command such as *apply to automate the process?

Answer (score 17):

Here is one way to automate the process

```
# read txt files with names of the form Patient*.txt
txt_files = list.files(pattern = 'Patient*.txt');

# read txt files into a list (assuming separator is a comma)
data_list = lapply(txt_files, read.table, sep = ",")
```

You can change the separator if you know what it is. It is convenient to keep the data as a list of data frames since it is easier to throw into a vectorized operation or loops later.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your recommendation but unfortunately it didn't work. I think that the problem is that the language samples are not in table format; they are free speech samples (E.g., "One day I went for a walk.... etc"). Ultimately what I would like to do is analyze the samples using some of the tools in the languageR package. To run the languageR functions though, first, I have to run the following command for each sample.
Patient130.txt <-scan("./Patient130.txt", what = "character")
Any idea how I can run scan for all samples instead of read.table?

Comment: @Mike Ferguson: try with `data_list = lapply(txt_files, scan, what = "character")` based on @Ramnath's suggestion.

Comment: Did you try Mike's suggestion? lapply is just a wrapper to loop across a list. Effectively, you are doing `lapply(txt_files, function(file) scan(file, what = "character"))`

Comment: @ Ramnath @daroczig That works pretty well. The only problem is that the labeling issue is not solved. When I type in "data_list" I can see the imported language samples but they are labeled [[1]], [[2]], ..., [[103]].If I want to proceed and only analyze selected language samples it is not clear how to do that.

Comment: @Mike Ferguson: try `lapply(txt_files, function(file) assign(file, scan(file, what = "character"), envir = .GlobalEnv))`

Comment: @daroczig I apologize if I am not communicating well what I would like to do. When I try your code here's what I get:
`> sample_files = list.files(".")
> sample_files
[1] "testFile.txt" "testFileena.txt"
> sample_files = list.files(".")
> sample_files
[1] "testFile1.txt" "testFile2.txt"
> data_list=lapply(sample_files, function(file) assign(file, scan(file, what = "character"), envir = .GlobalEnv))`
Read 3 items
Read 2 items
> data_list
[[1]]
 [1] "first" "you" "have"

[[2]]
 [1] "and" "then"
As you can see, I cannot see which patient the sample corresponds to. Any help?

Comment: @Mike Ferguson: with athe above command you should get distinct variables in the global environment named (see: `ls()`) to *Patient01.txt*, *Patient02.txt* and so on. Do not save the result of the list just loop through/run the command.

Comment: But you could also set the names of the list with the `names` function. Eg.: `names(data_list) <- txt_files`

Answer (score 1):

```
            files <- list.files(pattern = 'Patient*.txt')    
            for(i in files) {
            x <- read.table(i, header=TRUE, comment.char = "A", sep="\t")
            assign(i,x)  
            }
```